# Watermark in HTML form

Tags: html

Inside the form I would like to have my logo as Watermark. Very faded so the text is easy and good to read. I want to Watermark center and bigger But I'm stuck....any tips?

```
<form style="background: ##f7f8fa; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3); padding: 15px;">&nbsp;

<div>
<div id="image" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: relative;top: 0;left: 0;"><img src="https://ajrecruit-mhwbfrdhg9uflyxxtkv.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/HD_AJRecruit_Logo.png" /></div>
<div id="watermark" style="background:url(images/HD_AJRecruit_Logo.png) no-repeat; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; top: 0; left:0;"></div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against doing this as it will make the form harder to read.
If you must it's probably best to use a reduce the transparency of the PNG quite manually with photoshop/GIMP etc. Then try this:

```
form{
  background: background:url('https://ajrecruit-mhwbfrdhg9uflyxxtkv.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/HD_AJRecruit_Logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;
}
```

you can try background-size: cover | contain to make it larger but you'll need a larger image or it will be stretched.